# How can I find out the missing phpunit-skelgen in xampp for netBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp

I install the xampp 3.2.1 and netBeans 8.0 last night, trying to make some Yii framework projects.

I try to config the phpUnit for netBeans and open tools->options->php->framework&tools

asking me for the phpunit script and I found out where it is, c:\xampp\php\phpunit.bat

but the next one is phpunit-skelgen, which I don't know where to find...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpunit-skelgen in XAMPP for Netbeans can be added by using XAMPP shell.

1. Go to XAMPP shell by opening XAMPP control panel and click the Shell button.
2. Type `pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator`. Press Enter to install phpunit-skelgen.
3. Open Tools > Options > Frameworks and Tools. Click Search button alongside the Skeleton Generator Script. If phpunit_skeletongenerator has been installed successfully, it will show `C:\xampp\php\phpunit-skelgen.bat`.